# React Hooks TypeScript inheriting parent state & function types in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm looking for ways to inherit parent state & function types in child component so that I do not have to redefine them in child component.

I have parent component as follows:

```
const TagPopupModal: React.FC = () => {
// state
  const [addTagPressed, setAddTagPressed] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [tagList, setTagList] = useState<userTagType['tags'][]>(
    [],
  );

// function
  function addToTagList(tag: tagListType) {
   ...
  }

return (
  ...
  <TagListView 
    addTagPressed={addTagPressed}
    tagList={tagList}
    addToTagList={addToTagList}
  />
)
}
```

In parent component, I have defined the types for the state and parameter type for the function. Those are passed to child component.

Now in child component I have following:

```
interface PropTypes {
  addTagPressed:boolean;
  tagList: Array<userTagType['tags']>;
  addToTagList: (value: taglistType) => void;
}

const TagListView: React.FC<PropTypes> = ({
  addTagPressed, 
  tagList,
  addToTagList,
}) =>{
   ...
}
```

As you can see I had to define the same types for the props again, but using interface, in the child component. This is time-consuming, is there ways to directly inherit the types of the state and functions from the parent?

What would be the most efficient way?

Thanks,

Comment: where do you have duplication from what you have shown PropTypes is defined for TagListView component so where is the second place?

Comment: the types in PropTypes are already in parent component TagPopupModal component. It does not exist as an interface but as an individual when defined, as you can see for example : const [addTagPressed, setAddTagPressed] = useState<boolean>(false);  and for function parameter type, function addToTagList(tag: tagListType) {
   ...
  }

I am just creating the same type definition again using interface in child component.

Comment: One is state and one is props so you should have separate interfaces for them both. Export the interfaces from a shared file

Comment: @Mr.Robot how would we build an interface for the states for useState? As for functional components, I guess there is no place to add types(except adding individual type for useState) for state like class component? For example, we can do the following in class components: class Modal extends Component<PropTypes, StateTypes>{}, and export that StateType interface somewhere unlike exporting individual types for useState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could export your interface for PropTypes and consume that elsewhere, e.g. as `const [tagList, setTagList] = useState<PropTypes['tagList']>([]);`

You won't necessarily save much raw keyboard mashing, but it will help keep your types consistent and reusable.

```
import { TagListView, PropTypes } from '../TagListView';

const TagPopupModal: React.FC = () => {
// state
  const [addTagPressed, setAddTagPressed] = useState(false);
  const [tagList, setTagList] = useState<PropTypes['tagList']>(
    [],
  );

// function
  const addToTagList: PropTypes['addToTagList'] = (tag) => {
   ...
  }

return (
  ...
  <TagListView 
    addTagPressed={addTagPressed}
    tagList={tagList}
    addToTagList={addToTagList}
  />
)
}
```

Note that you don't need to be super vigilant about declaring explicit types in general. `useState(false)` for example will automatically infer the type of that state as `boolean`. And if you declare the function `addToTagList` as a const and set its type to be what is defined in `PropTypes`, TS will automatically know that the parameter `tag` is supposed to have a given type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So as for functional components, there is no place to add types(except adding individual type for useState) for state like class component? For example, we can do the following in class components: 
class Modal extends Component<PropTypes, StateTypes>{}, and export that StateType interface somewhere unlike exporting individual types for useState like above

Comment: Nope. But if you have *that much duplication* And tight coupling between state and props of nested components, it definitely would make me question why they are two separate components in the first place. Could they be combined somehow?

Comment: I could deal with adding another interface for props for child component. Was just wondering if there were other ways to efficiently deal with such situation. Thanks for reply!